# Highlight specific genes in boxplot

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that is composed by 200 genes (i.e. 200 rows) and 2 columns (i.e. Treated and Untreated). Values are the expression levels of the genes in the two conditions. I simply would like to plot a boxplot of the distribution of the two conditions of the 200 genes but highlighting with coloured dots only a subset of genes.

Moreover I would like to put in the plot the p-value (in this case I calculated it and is <0.001) of the comparison of the two conditions.

```
 df
        Gene        Treated       Untreated   
         A           0.12           0.12  
         B           12.4           0.003   
         C           3.4            0.32   
         D           8.9            0.1   
         E           1.28           0.32   
         F          -4.95           1.54   
         G          -5.93           0.87  
         H           11.2           0.76   
         I           9.8            1.06
```

Suppose to highlight genes: C,F,G,I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you a `ggplot2` answer. For this, you need to reshape your data, so there are separate x and y variables. Right now, your y values are split between two columns.

Then we highlight the specific genes by only plotting points for a subset.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gene_list <- c('C', 'F', 'G', 'I')
df_long <- gather(df, treatment, expression, -Gene)

ggplot(df_long, aes(treatment, expression)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(aes(color = Gene), filter(df_long, Gene %in% gene_list), size = 3) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(caption = 'p < 0.001')
```

[image]

For specific adjustments, please have a look at the many `ggplot2` questions here on SO.

Comment: Thank you very much Axeman. Is it possible to color dots according to a threshold? For example: all values > 1 will be red while the others will be black.